# Please one box Apple app store apps in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

It would be convenient if the one box code to expand a link in [chat] would handle Apple app store apps, iBooks, Movies, Music, Videos, etc...

- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/just-press-record-voice-audio/id1033342465?mt=8

Thanks for any votes or thought on if this would be a bad thing. My feeling is moderation would be able to handle any abuses of this, but I'm asking here to see if anyone thinks this would be helpful.

Comment: Good idea. We might need some discussion about what exactly should be shown in the box then: just icon/title or more?

Comment: I think it's really up to what the developer wants to code from what they can scrape. Slack does a nice job of this currently. http://i.stack.imgur.com/GY4jC.png

Comment: Open Graph tags `og:site_name`, `og:title`, `og:description`, and `og:image` provide all the information that would be needed. The [iTunes Search API](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/) could also work. I would suggest keeping the description short (i.e. truncation).

Comment: Is there any concern over affiliate links being used? Or even replacing/adding one for Stack to be the affiliate? (I'd be fine with that.)

Comment: I believe Stack Exchange already has code to strip out affiliate links. That would be another reason to handle them as opposed to let people post whatever link they craft. Good suggestion, @incumbent